# Im having trouble while trying to install 'flask-mysqldb' resulting in an error code 1

Tags: python, flask, pip, flask-mysql

[The Command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOXLs.png)

Whenever I type pip install flask-mysqldb it results in an error code 1, I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem and can help. I am using windows 7 64bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip fails to install github package 'python-ldap', C++ 10 required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907212/pip-fails-to-install-github-package-python-ldap-c-10-required)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install [Visual C++](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266) as instructed.
After that, re-run the command, but as Administrator.